issue with JpaSpecificationExecutor, cant apply record to projection
repository and projection
my version of spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:3.3.2, spring-boot-starter-parent also 3.3.2
JAVA_VERSION=17
public interface CustomRepository extends JpaRepository<CustomEntity, Integer>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<CustomEntity> {
}


public record CustomProjection(Long id,
                                String region,
                                LocalDateTime createdAt
                                ) {
}

ServiceMethod
Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(page, 1000, Sort.by("createdAt").descending());
        var data = customRepository.findBy(CustomJpaSpecification.statusEquals(StatusEnum.ACTIVE),
                q -> q.as(CustomProjection.class).page(pageable));

i see exception
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Class-based DTOs are not yet supported. at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.FetchableFluentQueryBySpecification.as(FetchableFluentQueryBySpecification.java:110) at kz.aitups.sw.voucher.gas.service.voucher.VoucherService.lambda$sendVouchers$8(VoucherService.java:135) at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.doFindBy(SimpleJpaRepository.java:539) at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findBy(SimpleJpaRepository.java:502) at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:354) at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:277) at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:170) at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:158) at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:516) at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:285) at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:628)
i dont have idea, i'v seen instruction here text
